# python-Can't get utf-8 string from sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to get some strings using SQLAlchemy.

```
tags = db.session.query(Tag.tag_name).order_by(Tag.tag_id).all()
```

`db` is my sqlite database. `tag_name` entities are `VARCHAR`.

When I'm debugging the program, it shows the tags variable is

```
{list}[(u'python',),(u'\u7f51',)]
```

Here `\u7f51` is a Chinese character.

As the project is based on `Flask` framework, I use `Jinja2` to show each tag in `tags`.

```
{% for tag in tags %}
<li><a href="#">{{tag}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

On the web page it shows exactly like `(u'python',)`.
I want the web page to show things like `python`, but I don't know how to deal with this strange list object. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

This should be very straight forward. The query result set is obtained in `tuple` format. So you have a list of tuples. And for *non-utf8* characters use `encode` function and use list comprehension to generate a list of strings.

You can do this:

```
tags = [r(0).encode('utf8') for r in tags]
```

Comment: I'm sorry. This is not the point. The problem is that in list `tags`, every tuple is of `result` class and every tuple is formatted as `(u'xxx')`. I can't figure out how to get rid of the brackets.

Comment: @PenguinGoHack: I have edited my answer based on your comment.

Comment: Returns `TypeError: 'result' object is not callable` Every tuple is of class `result`.

Comment: Hi, I've solved the problem by changing the HTML to `{{tag[0]}}`. Thanks for your help, anyway.